# A* efficiency vs Greedy Best First

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, heuristics

Given the following maze:

```
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|       | | |           |   |     | |
| ||||||| | ||| | ||| ||| ||||||| | |
|       |       | |     |     | |   |
||||| ||||| ||| | | | ||| ||||| | |||
|   | | | |   | | | |   | |   | |   |
| ||| | | | ||| ||||| ||| | ||| ||| |
|       |     |   |   |     | | |   |
||| ||||||||| ||||||| ||| ||| | | | |
|             |       | |   |     | |
| | ||||| | ||| | | ||| | ||| ||| | |
| | |     | | | | |     |   | | | | |
| | | ||||||| | ||||||||| ||| | ||| |
| | | |     |   |     |     |   |   |
||| ||| | ||||| ||||| ||| ||| ||||| |
|     | | |     | |     | |   | | | |
| | | | | ||| ||| ||| ||| | | | | | |
| | | | |                 | | |     |
||| ||||||| | | ||||| ||| | ||| |||||
|       | | | |     |   |     | |   |
||||| | | ||||||||| ||||||||||| | |||
|   | |           | |     |   | |   |
| ||| ||||| ||||||||| ||||| | | ||| |
| |   |      |        |     |       |
| | | ||||| ||| | | | | |||||||||||||
| | |   |     | | | |       |   | | |
| | ||| ||| | | | ||||||||| ||| | | |
| |   | |   | | |   | |   | | |     |
| ||| ||| ||||| ||| | | ||||| | |||||
|       |   |     | |     |   | |   |
||| | ||||| ||||| ||| ||| | ||| | |||
| | | | | | | |     | |   | |   | | |
| | ||| | | | | ||||||||| | | | | | |
|   |   |   |                 |     |
| | | | ||| ||| ||||||| ||| ||| ||| |
|+| | |       |   |       |   | |  P|
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

I have two results from two different algorithms (of which, I'm hoping are correct implementations of A* and Greedy First):

```
                                    #nodes searched; hops to goal
large maze - a* -                   expanded: 1120 (cost: 209)
large maze - greedy -               expanded: 916 (cost: 209)
```

Is this normal behavior? Is A* not always optimal *and* more efficient than other algorithms, given a single path? I know it's dependent on the problem setup, but this was replicated with a much larger test as well:

```
mega maze - a* -                    expanded: 8964 (837)
mega maze - greedy (mh heur) -      expanded: 5455 (837)
```

Am I wrong in thinking A* should have outperformed Greedy First here?
Below are my heuristics... maybe I'm setting my heuristic values wrong?:

```
#greedy
self.heuristic = abs(goalNodeXY[0] - self.xy[0]) + abs(goalNodeXY[1] - self.xy[1])

#A* --- costFromStart == path length from starting point
self.heuristic = math.hypot(self.xy[1]-goalNodeXY[1],self.xy[0]-goalNodeXY[0]) + costFromStart
```

Comment: What units are those numbers?  Seconds?  MB of RAM?

Comment: Sorry.. it's just node/path length. 1 hop = 1. I'll clarify in the question

Answer (score 3):

> Is A* not always optimal *and* more efficient than other algorithms, given a single path?

No. A* always finds an optimal path, but it does not always do so faster than other algorithms. It's perfectly normal for the greedy search to sometimes do better.

Also, your A* heuristic isn't as good as the one you used for the greedy algorithm. You used Manhattan distance in the greedy algorithm and Euclidean distance in the A* search; Manhattan distance is always a better estimate of the remaining path length and never overestimates, so it would have been better to use Manhattan distance in the A* search too.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this point? `Manhattan distance is always a better estimate of the remaining path length [vs Euclidean]` -- I just changed my heuristic for A* to be `MHD + currentCost`, but it expanded almost 200 additional nodes during the search compared to `Euclidean + currentCost`? is your point just in general?

Comment: @MrDuk: The remaining path length is at least the Manhattan distance from the current position to the goal, and the Manhattan distance is always at least the Euclidean distance. I wouldn't have expected the result you got, but it's certainly possible; using a more accurate heuristic usually reduces the number of nodes expanded, but it doesn't always.

Answer (score 1):

A good heuristic for A* is the one that approximates the remaining distance best (and also never exceeds it, if you need your A* to always find the best path). Since distance in your maze is defined as number of cells traversed, your greedy heuristic approximates if significantly better than the Euclid distance (hypot), because it predicts it perfectly for the case when there are no obstacles on the remaining part of the way, and is always closer to the real distance if there are obstacles.

So it is absolutely expected that your first approach outperforms your second approach.